# Error in creating new column in dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I have a df as shown below:

```
     id type start end features
1     5 word     1   2       NN
2     6 word     3   3        .
3     7 word     5  12       NN
4     8 word    14  19      VBZ
5     9 word    21  30       NN
6    10 word    32  32      WDT
7    11 word    34  37      VBP
8    12 word    39  41       IN
9    13 word    43  44       IN
10   14 word    46  46       DT
```

I want to create a new column "sum" with sum of each value in 'start' and 'end'.

I have created the following function:

```
    mySum <- function(row) {
      row["start"]+row["end"]
    }
    df$sum <- apply(df,1, mySum );
```

But when I run this I get following error:

```
Error in row["start"] + row["end"] : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

But if I keep only row["start"] or row["end"] in the function, it gets created.

I have also tried to force each value in the columns to be numeric.

```
df$start = as.integer(as.vector(df$start));
df$end = as.integer(as.vector(df$end));
```

But still I get the same error, only when I add the values.

The structure of my dataframe is as follows: 
After I ran `dput(droplevels(head(df,10)))`

```
structure(list(id = 5:14, type = c("word", "word", "word", "word", 
"word", "word", "word", "word", "word", "word"), start = c(1L, 
3L, 5L, 14L, 21L, 32L, 34L, 39L, 43L, 46L), end = c(2L, 3L, 12L, 
19L, 30L, 32L, 37L, 41L, 44L, 46L), features = list(structure(list(
    POS = "NN"), .Names = "POS"), structure(list(POS = "."), .Names = "POS"), 
    structure(list(POS = "NN"), .Names = "POS"), structure(list(
        POS = "VBZ"), .Names = "POS"), structure(list(POS = "NN"), .Names = "POS"), 
    structure(list(POS = "WDT"), .Names = "POS"), structure(list(
        POS = "VBP"), .Names = "POS"), structure(list(POS = "IN"), .Names = "POS"), 
    structure(list(POS = "IN"), .Names = "POS"), structure(list(
        POS = "DT"), .Names = "POS"))), .Names = c("id", "type", 
"start", "end", "features"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Note that, all casting issues taken apart, your error would probably change if you used :

    `mySum <- function(row) {
        as.integer(row[["start"]]) + as.integer(row[["end"]])
    }`

By definition, `row` cannot be the vector you think it is.

Answer (score 1):

Just do

```
df1$Sum <- df1[,'start']+ df1[,'end']
df1$Sum
#[1]  3  6 17 33 51 64 71 80 87 92
```

Or

```
rowSums(df1[c('start', 'end')], na.rm=TRUE)
#1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
#3  6 17 33 51 64 71 80 87 92
```

The `error` suggests that you have non-numeric columns.  Check the `str(df1)`.  If the class is `factor` or `character`, then change it to `numeric` and apply the code as above.  For example, if the columns are `factor`, we convert to `numeric` by

```
 df1[c('start', 'end')] <- lapply(df1[c('start', 'end')],
               function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

In case of `character` columns, just use `as.numeric`.

Comment: So the 'feature' column is a list and the 'type' column is a character. But what I don't understand is, I am using neither of that, I am using only 'start' and 'end' (which are numeric). Should I still update other columns?

Comment: @Mahesh As you are not using `feature` column and `type` column, it doesnt really matter.  What are the `class` of 'start' and 'end' columns?

Comment: I ran class(df$start) and class(df$end) and both gave "integer"

Comment: @Mahesh Can you update the post with the `dput` output i.e. `dput(droplevels(head(yourdata,10)))`

Comment: @Mahesh The sum part is working for me.  THe `features` column is a `list`, but it wouldn't affect with your aim.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96525/discussion-between-mahesh-and-akrun).